# Luhn algorithm implementation

Tags: haskell, luhn

I'm expecting `luhn 5594589764218858 = True` but it is always `False`

```
-- Get the last digit from a number
lastDigit :: Integer -> Integer
lastDigit 0 = 0
lastDigit n = mod n 10

-- Drop the last digit from a number
dropLastDigit :: Integer -> Integer
dropLastDigit n = div n 10

toRevDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toRevDigits n
  | n <= 0    = []
  | otherwise = lastDigit n : toRevDigits (dropLastDigit n)

-- Double every second number in a list starting on the left.
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther []       = []
doubleEveryOther (x : []) = [x]
doubleEveryOther (x : y : z) = x : (y * 2) : doubleEveryOther z

-- Calculate the sum of all the digits in every Integer.
sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits []          = 0
sumDigits (x : [])    = x
sumDigits (x : y)     = (lastDigit x) + (dropLastDigit x) + sumDigits y

-- Validate a credit card number using the above functions.
luhn :: Integer -> Bool
luhn n
  | sumDigits (doubleEveryOther (toRevDigits n)) `div` 10 == 0 = True
  | otherwise                                                  = False
```

I know it can be done easier but I'm following a Haskell [introductory](https://web.archive.org/web/20160630034720/http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/01-intro.pdf). I think my only problem is in the `luhn` function. The course mentions problems may occur because `toRevDigits` reverses the number but I think it should work anyways.

Comment: I would suggest writing some tests for each of those components (a good opportunity to learn quickcheck, if you have a little time).

Comment: @BradyDean Your `sumDigits` function is wrong. Consider this example. `lastDigit 123` returns `3`. `dropLastDigit 123` returns `12`. However `3 + 12` is not equal to the sum of the digits (`1 + 2 + 3`).

Comment: The digits are being split up. `sumDigits [10, 5, 18, 4] = 1 + 0 + 5 + 1 + 8 + 4 = 19` is what I'm going for

Comment: @BradyDean You're only getting a correct result in your example because all integers happen to have no more than two digits. Try `sumDigits [1,100]`.

Comment: @Jubobs Only handling values with at most two digits is sufficient in this case since `doubleEveryOther` will never yield numbers > 9*2.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe True; that's not even the problem, here. However, I find the name `sumDigits` misleading and I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: For what it's worth, a very concise definition for `doubleEveryOther` would be `doubleEveryOther = zipWith ($) (cycle [id, (*2)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet `` x `div` 10 == 0 `` is not a correct check that `x` is divisible by ten; you should use `` `mod` `` instead. Also, this equation is incorrect:

```
sumDigits (x : [])    = x
```

(Try, e.g. `sumDigits [10]`.) It can be fixed, but deleting it is simpler and still correct.

Comment: Wow I read over the code so many times and never noticed that. Code is working now with those changes.

Comment: @BradyDean In my experience, you can't uncover bugs by reading code. And I didn't in this case, either; I ran snippets of your code on a your hand-crafted example to see what it would do, and whether that matched what I expected, looking for the smallest function that didn't match my expectations. This is a powerful technique that I encourage you to adopt.

Comment: Yes I ran examples given in the course but I didn't have much to work with.